# A chess board with color and dimensions change(JS and PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm writing a simple chess board in HTML, CSS, JS and PHP. I want to add custom color to even and odd squares and a custom dimensions(height and width). I wanted to do it this way, but it doesn't work. It's my assignment for an upcoming exam, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<html> 
  <body>
    Select first color: 
    <select id="mySelect" onChange="changeColor(value);">
      <option value="black">Black</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
      <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    </select>
      <br><br>
    Select second color: 
    <select id="mySelect2" onChange="changeColor2(value);">
      <option value="white">White</option>
      <option value="brown">Brown</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="purple">Purple</option>
    </select>
      <br><br>
    Dimensions value:
    <input type="number" id="dimensions">
    <button type="button" onClick="changeDim">Hajde</button>
   <table width="270px" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px" border="1px">
      <?php
      for($row=1;$row<=8;$row++)
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          for($col=1;$col<=8;$col++)
          {
          $total=$row+$col;
          if($total%2==0)
          {
          echo "<td id='even'></td>";
          }
          else
          {
          echo "<td id='odd'></td>";
          }
          }
          echo "</tr>";
      }
      ?>
  </table>
      <script>
        function changeColor(color) {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById("par").style.background = color;
        }
        function changeColor2(color) {
        var x = document.getElementById("mySelect2").selectedIndex;
        document.getElementById("par").style.background = color;
        }
        function changeDim() {
        var px = "px";
        var dimension = document.getElementById("dimensions").value + px;
        document.getElementById("even").style.height = dimension;
        document.getElementById("even").style.width = dimension;
        document.getElementById("odd").style.height = dimension; 
        document.getElementById("odd").style.width = dimension;  
        }
      </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You will need to be more specific on how this is failing to work as expected. I do notice that you are using `id='even'` or odd when a document may have only 1 element per id. You probably intended to use `class='even'` / odd to apply a css class

Comment: Ok I scrolled farther and found you are calling `getElementById('even')` - that may not work as expected because ids are meant to be unique. If you switch to class, use `document.getElementsByClassName('even')` but you will need to loop over the resulting collection of elements to modify them

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just want to be able to access either the even or odd square.  You can do this with css if you are only changing styling.

You can do something like this to the table.  It also will flip to do the even and odd on the row since you said it was for a chess board.

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: black;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(even){
  background-color: black;
}
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck!
quick ex. https://jsfiddle.net/1c0b2ff0/5/